Register field access in uvm post_write/post_read callback tasks
I have a situation where in I need to know values of each field in a register through register callback operation. I can get value of register by rw.value[0]  in post_write/post_read task but not able to get the values by field of that register.
I tried post_predict by field but trying to see if this is possible by post_write/post_read callbacks .
Thank you in advance for any help or suggestion.
My expectation here is to just print register value and values of each field by field name through post_write/post_read register callback and write into a file for post processing.

I already tried rw.get_fields() and rw.element.get_fileds() in post_write/post_read callbacks and they did not work .

Please post a MRE.
